# Align 3 Divs side by side with position:Fixed

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need to align 3 div's floated side by side. Below is my code however all the DIV's appear under each other, i'm guessing this is because of the fixed position. However this is the positioning I need for my website.

.one is sidelinks bar which I would like to have a min width: of 150px 
.two is for adverts and instructions links 
.three is a long div filled with data which needs to be scrollable. I tried to may methods but nothing works could jquery help? I want all to be of fixed position. I would also like the DIVs to remain the same size when the window is minimized.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.one {
    height:50px;
    width:34%;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    position:fixed;
    }
.two {
    height:50px;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed;
    }   
.three{
    height:50px;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:scroll;
    }   
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
<div class="three">three</div>

</body>
</html>
```

FOLLOW ON EDIT:

I'm able to split the DIVS apart but then the window is minimised the .two div floats over the .one div. see image https://postimg.cc/kDQSJpDR

```
.one {
    height:50px;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    position:fixed;
    min-width:200px;
    }
.two {
    height:50px;
    width:33%;
    margin-left: 34%;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed;
    }   
.three{
    height:50px;
    width:33%;
    margin-left: 68%;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:scroll;
    }
```

Comment: `.one`, 150px (min)  `.two`, variable width(?)  `.three`, scrollable and you do not want them to stack on top of eachother for small screens, correct? But you have `width:33%`; for all of the columns. Should they be the same size, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want something like this?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.justify-start {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.p-fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.w-150px {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.wh-100v {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.wh-100p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.overflow-scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container justify-start wh-100v p-fixed">
  <div class="w-150px flex-grow pink"></div>
  <div class="wh-100p flex-grow red"></div>
  <div class="wh-100p flex-grow green overflow-scroll text-justify">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

If so, [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and a container as what @elbrant suggested is all that you'll need. Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/MZWyvG?editors=1100) :)

A quick note: Since both our flex-items' `flex-grow` property is set to the same value, those two above-mentioned items will always equally occupy their parent regardless of its size.

Answer (score 0):

```
    please add "margin-left:34%" in .two css and "margin-left:68%" in .three css.

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.one {
    height:50px;
    width:34%;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    position:fixed;
    }
.two {
    height:50px;
    width:33%;
    margin-left: 34%;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed;
    }   
.three{
    height:50px;
    width:33%;
    margin-left: 68%;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:scroll;
    }   
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
<div class="three">three</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .one, .two, .three {
                top:0;
                position:fixed;
                height:50px;
            }
            .one {
                left:0;
                width:34%;
                background-color:red;
            }
            .two {
                left:34%;
                width:33%;
                background-color:blue;
            }   
            .three{
                left:67%;
                width:33%;
                background-color:green;
                overflow:scroll;
            }   
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="one">one</div>
        <div class="two">two</div>
        <div class="three">three</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make sure that your columns are in a set position (regardless of screen size) is to wrap them in a container.

**CSS changes**
Each of these grid-areas contain a series of numbers which designate where their sides are by top/left/bottom/right telling us that the sides of column `.one` are located at the position 1/1/2/2. It will be easier to understand if you draw a rectangle on a piece of scrap paper and put two lines in it from top to bottom, a rough draft of your column placement. Count your lines based on each column. For the first column: the top of the rectangle is line 1, the bottom is line 2. The left is line 1, the right side is line 2. Represented by 1/1/2/2. 
 That gives each of your columns a fixed position.

```
.one {
    grid-area: one 1/1/2/2;
    height:150px;
    min-width:150px;
    background-color:red;
    }

.two {
    grid-area: two 1/2/2/3;
    height:150px;
    min-width:150px;
    background-color:blue;
    }

.three{
    grid-area: three 1/3/2/4;
    height:150px;
    min-width:150px;
    background-color:green;
    overflow:scroll;
    }

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template areas: 'one two three';
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: center;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    }

 .grid-container > div {
    margin: 5px;
    padding 0;
    }
```

**HTML changes**

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
</div><!-- end container div -->
```